# PHP strpos() IS case sensitive for me

Tags: php, strpos

When I use `strpos()` it is case sensitive. Why? Isn't it not supposed to be?

PHP v5.3.8

```
$file_check_result = "%PDF-1.6 %âãÏÓ";
$test = strpos($file_check_result, "pdf");
echo $test;
```

Outputs nothing; if however I change `pdf` to `PDF` in `strpos` it shows position. Why?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`stripos` is the function that you are looking for. `strpos` is case sensitive

http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php

Comment: Darn i guess i was too tired because i read "case-insensitive" as case sensitive, i sometimes skip meaning when i read fast...

Answer (score 4):

The case-insensitive one is [`stripos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php) (note the **i**):

```
strpos()   // Finds the position of the first occurrence (case-sensitive)
stripos()  // Finds the position of the first occurrence (case-insensitive)
strrpos()  // Finds the position of the last occurrence (case-sensitive)
strripos() // Finds the position of the last occurrence (case-insensitive)
```